# Wait for dependencies to load before starting spring boot service

Tags: java, spring-boot, autowired, postconstruct, spring-scheduled

I have a spring boot application which has two beans - `AppState` and `Users`.
`AppState` depends on the bean `Users` as it autowires it. The skeleton codes for the two beans are as follows.

```
@Component
@EnableScheduling
public class Users {
    @Getter // lombok
    private List<String> users;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        users = new ArrayList<>();
        load(); // I removed this later
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 3600000)
    public void load(){
        // load list of users from (say) a file and populate ArrayList 'users'
        // this method takes at least 3 mins to finish
    }
}
```

`AppState` is

```
@Component
public class AppState {
    @Atowired
    private Users users;

    public List<String> getUsers(){
        return users.getUsers();
    }
}
```

I noticed that the method `load()` in `Users` was getting triggered twice - probably once during `init()` and the other time while scheduling `load()` right after `Users` bean had been created. So I removed the call to `load()` in `init()`. This fixed the redundant call issue.

However, now I find that my service starts as soon as `AppState` and `Users` beans have been created, even though `Users` has not been populated with data yet. This is risky for me as the service, during this time, will return 0 users if queried.

I need help with ANY of the following.

- Should I move `load()` back into `init()` to make sure that when the bean is done with `PostConstruct`, it does have all users info? If I go this route, how can I prevent redundant run of `load()`?
- If `load()` should stay out of `init()`, how can I ensure that `AppState` is not ready unless `Users` has executed `load()`? I tried using the following code in `AppState` but it just hangs.

The code is as follows.

```
@PostConstruct
public void appStateInit(){
    while(users.getUsers().size()==0){
        try{
            Thread.sleep(10000); // sleep 10s
        }catch(whatever){
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest having a `flag` in the class and setting it to `true` once init() has finished. You can skip the execution of `load()` if `flag` is not set yet, e.g.:

```
private AtomicBoolean shouldExecute;

@PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        users = new ArrayList<>();
        shouldExecute = true;
    }

@Scheduled(fixedRate = 3600000)
public void load(){
    if(shouldExecute){
       // load list of users from (say) a file and populate ArrayList 'users'
    // this method takes at least 3 mins to finish
    } 
}
```

Also, another solution will be to configure `initialDelay` in `@Scheduled` annotation (documentation [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html)) which would delay the first execution by configured number of milliseconds, e.g:

```
    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 3600000, initialDelay=180000)
    public void load(){
        // load list of users from (say) a file and populate ArrayList 'users'
        // this method takes at least 3 mins to finish
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I like the `initialDelay` approach.